# C# Windows Forms Application with MS-Access deployment

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, deployment

What is the easiest way to deploy a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) application that uses an [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) database?  Using Visual Studio 2010's Installer, I cannot seem to get the database deployed to a common directory for all users of the PC to access it.

Searching the web, I have found tons of issues, but no simple solutions.

Comment: Many users on the same machine or many users on a internal network accessing the database from many connected PC?

Answer (score -2):

you can't find a directory that can be accessed by all users of the PC? maybe you can deploy the database to a special directory using the special enum named Environment.SpecialFolder, such as "CommonApplicationData" or "CommonProgramFiles".

Comment: Would appreciate a little more detail (maybe sample code.)  (e.g. how to do this in VS2010 Installer, how to declare this location in ConnectionString, how to grant write access, etc.)